# Switching loss calculation formula

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, switching-losses

I read an [article](https://www.eetimes.com/estimating-mosfet-switching-losses-means-higher-performance-buck-converters/) talking about the power switching loss formula, and I am curious about one thing.

[image]

How to use math to prove the 1/6 and 1/2 in these two waveforms? Could someone give me some idea?

Comment: Being proportional to FS is obvious... And simple integration of "straight line" definitions for Vds and Id.

Comment: 1/2 in the second one is due to the two slopes coming after each other if you count the area under the graph. 1/6 is due to one rising while the other one is falling. Less intuitive. Derive the formula or count the area under the graph I * V.

Comment: @winny Yes, but I'd like to know how to prove it.

Comment: @EEC Are you familiar with integral calculus? The most straightforward way to derive the formula is to just integrate the product of V and I.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These expressions let you calculate the theoretical losses when a power switch turns on or off with overlapping current and voltage.

I have carried the calculations in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) for the two scenarios and the turn-off sequence in particular. The calculation is quite simple and involves an integral to average the instantaneous power \$p(t)\$ over a switching period. The below figure shows you a real shot taken on a flyback converter when the switch opens:

[image]

Please note that these are idealized waveforms and switching losses are extremely difficult to theoretically evaluate. This is because many parasitics (components, layout and so on) are involved which can significantly affect final waveforms. Same with simulation which usually leads to wrong results for switching losses.

Comment: HI Verbal,
Could you tell me which topic in your book talks about math equations in 1/2?
I do not find this equation in your book.

Comment: Hello, in the second edition, this is in the 20-W design example, equations (7.261) and (7.262).

Comment: Hi, I do not find the 7.261 in the second edition. could you tell me which page?

Comment: How come you can't find an equation number?? It is page 736, second edition, green book, in the 20-W design example.

Comment: Verbal, 
I find it! thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the "starting" idea ...

Formulas being proportional to FS is obvious.

Integration done for **ONE** cycle. So, multiply by frequency.

[image]

Next case :

[image]

Comment: Hi Antonio,

Thanks. could you also tell me the other?

Comment: @EEC Added in answer.

Comment: it seems like you use the triangle formula right? 
the equation is very clear, thanks.

Comment: Yes. In this linear case, Maple does so with operator "integrate" within two limits: int(f(t),t), but it is very general for other functions and so easily ...